# Any recommendation for hosting provider for hosting Wordpress CMS website (not just a blog)?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress

I want to host a Wordpress CMS based website. Any recommendations for a easy and reliable hosting provider. I have heard about lots of issues when hosting wordpress with my current host. This is based on Wordpress version 3.0.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is asking for a list of recommendations and opinions, there is not a single possibly 'correct' answer, so I have converted this to community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Hostgator hasn't been bad to me and my company. They're cheap, reliable, and their customer service is excellent. If you need to scale up or down, they can accommodate your needs pretty well.

Comment: Seconding Hostgator. Their tech support availability and responsiveness is great.

Comment: Third on Hostgator.  Great service, good value, and no gotchas that I've found so far.  Kudos too on the referral program if you're like me and find yourself referring a lot of people for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I would **avoid** 1and1.  Proprietary control panel, limited phpMyAdmin interface, and outsourced tech support have made them a huge headache for me.  I'm in the process of switching (to Hostgator) right now.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using dream host for a couple of years now. I host a couple of wordpress installations on it (one is just a blog, one was part of an integrated site). They're competitively priced, very easy to use, and quick to respond to any problems on their end.

Answer (score 1):

I just setup a Wordpress site as a small CMS for my son's scout pack.  I used siteground.com.  So far it is working great.  The siteground admin interface had a button to auto install Wordpress.  The process took about 5 seconds to complete...not the 15+ minutes that I have see with other hosts.

Siteground pricing is good for basic hosting, but their SSL certificates are a bit more expensive than I expected, starting around $100.   I don't need SSL, but if you do make sure you factor in the price.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few wordpress sites, some as blogs and some as CMS and have not seen a difference in their hosting needs.

If it is good for a blog it is good for a CMS. The only thing that is important is the usage of the site. You need a package with enough space and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I have been quite happy with [Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com).

Comment: I would avoid Bluehost at all cost.  Check out their response to a recent security issue: http://blog.sucuri.net/2010/06/bluehost-talks-down-malware-percentages.html

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com)

They have a stunning panel for managing your web server and offer a LOT of one click installers for everything you need these days (Wordpress, Django, Joomla, Drupal, Trac, Subversion, whatever!).

You even get SSH access to your web server and thus can setup cronjobs or even install new software (for example you could setup your own Git or Subversion repositories).

They might be a bit more expensive than other web hosts but their support is absolutely stunning. I got replies on late Sunday evenings. Each conversation I hat with the support staff resulted in real answers by real people, no template rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

**ENGINEHOSTING**

I highly recommend [enginehosting.com](http://enginehosting.com). They specialize in EE, but their support team is amazing.

They are a bit different than other shared hosting companies because they manage just about everything themselves. Other than you files and website.

*(Note: they are not really a shared hosting company. They also provide VPS and Dedicated hosting.)*

Also, they give you sFTP; which is very nice for shared hosting and Wordpress. Many shared providers do not make secure FTP easy to get at.

Excellent up time and loading speed!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.squarespace.com/. Super easy to use, setup, and maintain. They have a really slick interface for customizing your layout. The examples section has a ton of variations of the different types of sites. And they can scale capacity if you get suddenly digged or slashdotted. They have an easy import/export process of your existing blog. The price is pretty reasonable for what you get, and you can find coupon codes if you look. Also they have a 2week free trial (as of this writing...).

Otherwise, pretty much any well-respected shared host should be enough as long as you don't have very high traffic. The biggest drain on a CMS is database calls and to a lesser extent PHP usage (I tend to think the DB has more of a performance hit). You can mitigate that to an extent with caching in Wordpress.

If you do have a lot of traffic then you should take a look at VPS solutions, which give you a lot more performance and customization/optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small site then you should consider [NearlyFreeSpeech](http://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/). Instead of monthly plans they charge you for what you use. The downside is that they only support PHP (with safe mode) and CGI for scripting.